# filter jqgrid data

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have loaded a jqGrid with Json data.

What I need to do now is allow the end user to show only rows that have a null value in any one of four columns.

Assuming the following grid

```
col1|col2|col3|
  a   b        
  a   b     c
```

I want the user to be able to click a button and show only the first row.

I'm pretty new with jqGrid so please keep that in mind when replying.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve show or hide column based on the null value in afterInsertRow event.

Try this

```
       afterInsertRow: function(rowid,rowdata,rowelem){
         if(rowdata['col1']!=null && rowdata['col2']!=null && rowdata['col1']==null  ){   
        $("#"+rowid).hide();
                               }
                           },
```

Comment: to make sure I understand this: would I have to destroy/recreate the grid hiding the rows as it goes along? or would I be able to just call that function?

Comment: You can add this to your grid like you add other grid events. This wont recreate the grid. This function will be called after a row is added to the grid